# Re: Cisco switch and telnet

Tags: networking

I have configured the cisco switch with the following:

Current configuration:

```
!
version 12.0
no service pad
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
no service password-encryption
!
hostname protec
!
enable secret 5 $1$3GSJ$A0TryiEdaSegNfA2kr6kg0
enable password cisco
!

!
ip subnet-zero
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface VLAN1
 ip address 172.30.2.180 255.255.255.0
 no ip directed-broadcast
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway 172.30.2.1
banner motd ^C
*******************************
YOU MUST LOG ON
*******************************
^C
!
line con 0
 password Aaniyafreya78
 login
 transport input none
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password cisco
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
end
```

I have also turned my firwall & anti virus off.

When i try to telnet to the switch from my Laptop which has windows 7 installed, i receive the below error:

```
C:\Users\Windows7>telnet 172.30.2.1
Connecting To 172.30.2.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

why am i receiving this error? i can ping on a general base, but i cannot ping the above ip nor can i telnet to it. what else do i need to do on the switch to be able to access it remotely?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "I can ping on a general base"?

Comment: I had this same problem. The problem actually lies with the computer itself. Telnet is disabled by default on Windows, you have to activate it. Please review the instructions below, I will add this as the answer if it solves your problem.  http://www.wikihow.com/Activate-Telnet-in-Windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the ip address? Probably not.... this is because you are missing your vlan 1 db entry need to assign a interface to vlan 1.

If you do a "show vlan brief" what results to you get?

Assign your interface that the data cable is connected to to the the vlan; I chose  interface fastethernet 0/1 for this example.

Commands:

    1.conf t

    2.int fa0/1

    3.switchport access vlan 1

    4.no shut

Now try to ping the switch before using telnet.

Also, you don't need to put password cisco on the vty code unless you wont to enforce a different password set from the already specified user password.

Comment: protec#sh vlan brief
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -----    default                              active    Fa0/1, Fa0/2,Fa0/3,Fa0/4,Fa0/5, Fa0/6, 
1002 fddi-default                     active
1003 token-ring-default               active
1004 fddinet-default                  active
1005 trnet-default                    active
protec#

Comment: yeah you still need assign interfaces to vlan 1 (Think of it like its a new virtual switch).. use my config above to assign port fa0/1 then plug in you pc and try to ping it ps <-> switch. Also, your example of where you trying to connect is not the switch but the default-gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Switch IP is 172.30.2.180, but the OP's example shows he's telnet-ing to 172.30.2.1.  Or am I missing something...?

```
interface VLAN1
 ip address 172.30.2.180 255.255.255.0
 no ip directed-broadcast
 no ip route-cache
```

Comment: good catch but he still needs assign ports for connectivity to comm with his default gateway... which is 172.30.2.1

Answer (score 0):

From line console try to telnet the ip address of the switch but first verify the state of phisycal interface with "Show ip int brief".

Comment: This answer can be a bit clearer. Can you edit it to add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The ***default-gateway*** is for the switch to be managed **remotely**, from another network (thats probably from another IP range).
*Default-gateway* address is usually assigned as the ip address of the **L3 device** (router's interface) connected to the switch.
But if you are in VLAN 1 of your switch ' *protec* ', you need to ***telnet*** to the ip address of *interface VLAN 1* :-

***telnet 172.30.2.180***

This oughta work! Enjoy

Answer (score -2):

if this is a fairly new equipment or an old with with security measures updated on it, more than likely telnet is disabled as a communication protocol, due to its insecure nature. try connecting using ssh protocol (download putty if you have to; if you don't know what it is, just Google it)

Comment: This wouldn't fix his problem, most likely the computer has no communication to the switch as the code indicates.

Comment: then waht do you get as a response to `telnet 172.30.2.1 22` command ? If it is the same, you may be right and your connection to this device might have been cut off totally by some firewall or routing rule, but if you are getting a response like `openSSH...`, my answer still holds. Just check it. it won't hurt